# How do 2 people sign a transaction from different clients?

Tags: transactions, security, payments

In the multisig example located in the developer documents everything is listed in sequence in a single client "session" so to speak.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#multi-signature-account

The way I understood multisig to be useful is that 'rootKeypair' (person A) is able to enable multisig on the account with 'secondKeypair' (person B).

Then a week later (for example) 'rootKeypair' creates a payment. Following that 'secondKeypair is able to sign the transaction N minutes later from a separate client when they're ready to approve.

Is this correct? If so, how does the transaction get moved between clients? Does it happen on the network?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this flow is working on the backend process. You create transaction with signed rootKeypair and save transaction object somewhere else waiting for person B to signed that transaction ?

Comment: I was thinking about that as well. Wondering if you can serialize the transaction to XDR and pass the payload off to another client.

Comment: @RossBates yes, you can easily serialize XDR of the transaction envelope to base64 encoded string.

Comment: @BartekNowotarski awesome thanks, that's good to know. So would this be an approach for "sending" a transaction to a co-signer before submitting it to the network? This is all assuming that I don't have access to the second key, someone else has it and will be signing the transaction on a separate client.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to submit transaction to the network without all required signatures so you have to use another channel.